# How do I query a Table in SQL Server and filter by Column Name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Is there a way to:

```
SELECT * 
From a Table_Name 
Where the_Column_name like '%Application%'
```

I would like to filter by the actual column name and not what is found inside the column.

For example, I have a table with 10 columns, where the product columns are referring to eight specific items (colors).  The first column is the record Id and the final column represents the entry Date.

The table columns would look like the following:

```
Id, App1Red, App1Blue, App1Green, App1Yellow, App2Red,App2Blue, App2Green, App2Yellow, CollectDate
```

I am collecting integer values, which increase over time.

```
1, 20, 25, 32, 48, 40, 10, 56, 29, 2023-04-10 14:19:4.9166667
2, 22, 26, 48, 50, 49, 15, 58, 30, 2023-04-11 14:2:1.9166667
3, 24, 28, 49, 52, 53, 55, 60, 32, 2023-04-12 14:20:42.9166667
...
```

I need to generate a Select Statement that provides the value for each column, where the Date is the most recent date; such that, in the case above, a query for App1 would return Row 3 with the values of 24, 28, 49, and 52.

Therefore, the result set of my query should only contain data from One App, including its colors.

Comment: The core of the problem is the design of your table. These columns should be represented *as rows* in your dataset - then filtering them would be much easier.

Comment: You'll have to write out all relevant column names in your query. Depending on your goal you could apply sql UNION to combine 6 queries

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Your table has a fundamental design flaw that you absolutely must fix, read up on how to normalise a database schema. What happens when you need 20 applications and 50 colours...?

Comment: @Stu, with the dynamic solution he's asking for, it will be no problem, just add the columns and they will automatically appear! /s

Comment: I think the point is with a proper design there should be no need for any dynamic solution, proper normalisation should remove any occurence of data properties represented as table structure.

Comment: My design is based on my requirements.  I am working on developing an inventory database for 200 Stores.  Each store has a Unique ID and carries a specific set of merchandise that I need to track.  The 24 columns are some of the merchandise that I am tracking.  The StoreID is one of the Columns and the merchandise names follow.  The columns reflect the amount in inventory.  So far the queries for a list are returning correctly and an index on StoreID keeps the Where Statements fast.  I am trying to avoid creating Views by searching for Column Names. Information_schema is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to select certain columns dynamically is dynamic SQL, which I don't really recommend since it's going to be a custom query. The output from dynamic SQL is not really known until examining the string at the end and syntax errors are common and very hard to debug.

A test database is:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 Id int, App1Red int, App1Blue int, App1Green int, App1Yellow int, 
 App2Red int,App2Blue int, App2Green int, App2Yellow int , CollectDate datetime
)
GO

INSERT INTO test VALUES
 (1, 20, 25, 32, 48, 40, 10, 56, 29, '2023-04-10 14:19:04')
,(2, 22, 26, 48, 50, 49, 15, 58, 30, '2023-04-11 14:02:01')
,(3, 24, 28, 49, 52, 53, 55, 60, 32, '2023-04-12 14:20:42')
GO
```

The dynamic method uses INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, like in @lenalbert's answer. The rest is my custom query.

```
DECLARE @tablename varchar(50) = 'Test';
DECLARE @tableschema varchar(50) = 'dbo';
DECLARE @columnRegEx varchar(50) = 'App1%';
DECLARE @filterColumn varchar(50) = 'CollectDate';
DECLARE @filterValue varchar(50) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), (SELECT MAX(CollectDate) FROM test), 121);
DECLARE @sqlcommand nvarchar(max);

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT STUFF((
SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE @columnRegEx
  AND TABLE_NAME = @tablename
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @tableschema
FOR XML PATH('') 
), 1, 1, '') AS mycolumns
) --CTE

SELECT @sqlcommand = 
  CONCAT('SELECT' ,mycolumns, ' FROM ', @tableschema, '.', @tablename
         ,' WHERE ', @filterColumn, ' = ''', @filterValue, ''';' 
        )
  FROM CTE

SELECT @sqlcommand as [sqlcommand]; --if you want to view the Select query

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlcommand; --if you want to execute the Select query
```

Produces output:

```
sqlcommand
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT App1Blue, App1Green, App1Red, App1Yellow FROM dbo.Test WHERE CollectDate = '2023-04-12 14:20:42.000';    


App1Blue    App1Green   App1Red     App1Yellow
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
28          49          24          52
```

The `forxml()`  and `stuff()` trick is documented online in a few different places, for example https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/

`Forxml()` gets the rows from the query into 1 column. `Stuff()` removes the first comma from the output. There is a concatenation of strings, which could be a mystery until you read the string it produces, but generally we follow the syntax of a select clause, from clause, and where clause. I pre-calculate the max date in the table, and convert it to a string before it is passed-into the where clause (since we are dealing with saving content to a string and not the datetime datatype).

### Is there a better way?

There's a more traditional way.

If you pass a value to a stored procedure, it can be interpreted and run some code dynamically based on it's value (basically IF statements).  Some advantages of stored procedures: we can easily index the queries, the code is saved and pre-compiled on the backend, we can include comments and documentation, and our network does not have to pass long dynamic strings.  We also do not have to spell our columns a certain way for conditional output.

I can create a stored procedure that accepts an integer parameter.  In this simple example the SP check for the number 1 or 2 being passed.  If 1 is passed, then we select columns matching condition 1, else we select columns matching condition 2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AppNum @appnum int
AS
 DECLARE @thecollectdate datetime = (SELECT MAX(CollectDate) FROM test)

 IF @appnum = 1 
 BEGIN
  SELECT App1Red, App1Blue, App1Green, App1Yellow
    FROM test
   WHERE CollectDate = @thecollectdate 
 END

 ELSE IF @appnum = 2
 BEGIN
   SELECT App2Red, App2Blue, App2Green, App2Yellow
     FROM test
    WHERE CollectDate = @thecollectdate
 END
```

We can now index the columns in those select queries for efficiency just by looking at the code in the stored procedure:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ncx_AppNum_app1 ON dbo.Test (CollectDate DESC)
 INCLUDE (App1Red, App1Blue, App1Green, App1Yellow)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ncx_AppNum_app2 ON dbo.Test (CollectDate DESC)
 INCLUDE (App2Red, App2Blue, App2Green, App2Yellow)
```

To run the example code you just pass 1 or 2 into the stored procedure:

```
EXEC dbo.AppNum @appnum = 1; --fully covering index seek, choosing app1
EXEC dbo.AppNum @appnum = 2; --fully covering index seek, choosing app2
```

Will produce output:

```
App1Red     App1Blue    App1Green   App1Yellow
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
24          28          49          52


App2Red     App2Blue    App2Green   App2Yellow
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
53          55          60          32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` or `sys.columns` (Microsoft SQL Server) to find all the column based on their names.

Something like that might work ...

```
SELECT     *
FROM       table, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE      COLUMN_NAME LIKE "Application%Red"
```

You might need to use prepare statement to dynamically set the column name if that doesn't work directly like that.

Comment: I tried but all the data are returned.  No filtering on the Reds occurred.  Any other ideas?
SELECT     *
FROM       SalesReport, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE      COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'Margarita%'

Comment: @Johnny a big problem here is you haven't shown us your expected output, nor provided example data to work with.  Your question is a bit vague.  And we can guess all day what you are getting at like lenalbert just did and waste our time trying to write random code for you that you reject since it doesn't do *** exactly *** what you want.

Comment: @Zorkolot, thank you for your recommendations.  I have reworded the Question.  I hope it is clear that I would like to query, utilizing the Column names as a filter.

Comment: @Johnny thanks Johnny.  I can try answering the question using dynamic SQL but can also provide an example of a stored procedure as an alternative.